# "I intend it to sing" - old English sentence structure or idiom?

Tags: phrases

While watching the series "The Terror" I came upon a sentence concerning an eulogy:

> It will have to act as the only eulogy our boy Graham will be given out here.
>   And I intend it to sing.

In this case, is it an old-fashioned way of saying "I will sing these words out" or is it an idiom meaning "I intend it to be good."?

Thank you in advance for your input.

Comment: I take it to mean that the eulogy will be more than merely good - it will be so lyrical, so moving, so evocative that people will feel uplifted to have heard it.

Comment: No, this is perfectly correct in modern English.